# NullReferenceException при поиске с использованием GameObject.Find

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, find

Создал кнопку, которая при нажатии ищет панель `Window (Delete)`. Снизу скрипт.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Actions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Delete()
    {
        //int id = gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponent<Id>().id;
        GameObject DeleteWindow = GameObject.Find("Window (Delete)");
        print(DeleteWindow);
        //DeleteWindow.GetComponent<Delete>().id = id;
        //DeleteWindow.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

К моему удивлению результат возвращается пустым и из-за этого выскакивает ошибка

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

*Скриншот [тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdQb8.png) и снизу.*

[image]

---

Такие ошибки со мной начали встречаться часто.
Наконец-то кто-нибудь подскажите мне - **где моя ошибка?**

Comment: **Твоя ошибка**  в том что ты пользуешся `GameObject.Find`. Это грязные костыли.

Comment: @Yaroslav меня когда учили, показывали этот метод и я даже не знал что есть кое что ещё. В VS описание его 'Ищет GameObject во всём сцене'. Откуда мне знать что эта функция костильная?

Comment: Откуда? И не откуда и отовсюду, как не странно. Чем больше общих знаний, тем больше понимания. Вообще-то всё в какой-то мере костыли и даже, как-бы это не было странно базовый тип `string`! Без одних реально тяжело, но альтернативы ещё хуже, а без других обойтись не сложно и они ну очень грузные и плохие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GameObject.Find` ищет только активные объекты. А у вас эта панель, судя по скрину, выключена.

Попробуйте искать с помощью `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll`. Он вроде как и неактивные объекты тоже вернёт.

Comment: Нужно немного времени чтобы проверить ваш ответ.

Comment: Ну да ваш метод работает, но как мне найти определённый объект. Может пройти по этому списку с проверкой или есть вариант получше?

Comment: @AltF4 вообще методы типа `Find` не рекомендуют использовать. Почему бы не добавить в кнопку публичную ссылку на `GameObject` и в редакторе не перетащить туда эта панельку?

Comment: Я что-то типа этого пробовал, получил ошибку. Думаю проблема в том что я не знаю как правильно это делается.

Comment: @AltF4 ну, я же не могу угадать, где там ошибка была. Можете попробовать отдельным вопросом расписать с подробным описанием. Попробуем помочь (:

Comment: Это позже, во время оптимизации :-)